# Статические файлы на внешнем сервере

Tags: php

Стоит задача перенести все изображения товаров с сервера А на сервер Б.
Сервер А обрабатывает загрузку изображений, накладывает водяные знаки, создает копии в разных размерах. Вся обработка происходит в PHP
Сервер Б должен только хранить эти изображения и отдавать пользователю (можно через поддомен или примонтировав раздел на сервер А).

Вопрос каким образом лучше организовать передачу изображений и их удаление?
Думал примонтировать папки через sshfs, но на сколько это надежно? Интересует самый надежный метод, что бы не было ошибок из-за соединения.

Comment: а `scp`  не вариант ?..

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System отлично работает до появления сверхнагрузок на файловую систему. Примонтированная папка показывается в системе как локальная. Либо https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV и обращаться по http(s)